# C function changes behaviour depending on whether it has a call to printf in it

Tags: c, printf

I have a function that processes some data and finds the threshold that classifies the data with the lowest error. It looks like this:

```
void find_threshold(FeatureVal* fvals, sampledata* data, unsigned int num_samples, double* thresh, double* err, int* pol) {
    //code to calculate minThresh, minErr, minPol omitted
    printf("minThresh: %f, minErr: %f, minPol: %d\n", minThresh, minErr, minPol);
    *thresh = minThresh;
    *err = minErr;
    *pol = minPol;
}
```

Then in my test file I have this:

```
void test_find_threshold() {
    //code to set up test data omitted
    find_threshold(fvals, sdata, 6, &thresh, &err, &pol);

    printf("Expected 5 got %f\n", thresh);
    assert(eq(thresh, 5.0));
    printf("Expected 1 got %d\n", pol);
    assert(pol == 1);
    printf("Expected 0 got %f\n", err);
    assert(eq(err, 0.0));
}
```

This runs and the test passes with the following output:

```
minThresh: 5.000000, minErr: 0.000000, minPol: 1
Expected 5 got 5.000000
Expected 1 got 1
Expected 0 got 0.000000
```

However if I remove the call to printf() from find_threshold, suddenly the test fails! Commenting out the asserts so that I can see what gets returned, the output is:

```
Expected 5 got -15.000000
Expected 1 got -1
Expected 0 got 0.333333
```

I cannot make any sense of this whatsoever.

Comment: The problem may like in the code you omitted (//code to calculate minThresh, minErr, minPol omitted)

Comment: What you've written looks good to me at first glance, so the actual error probably lies in the code you have omitted.  Are you sure that when you remove the `printf` call, the code after it is still being executed?  Can you run this in a source-level debugger (such as gdb)?

Comment: Where and how are minThresh, minErr, minPol defined?

Comment: This may be an optimizer bug. I would try compiling with all optimizations disabled to see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Don't eliminate code from your test case right before posting on SO!  What you should do is write a minimal test case---which you can't explain---and post that.  More advice in this vein: http://sscce.org/ http://www.xs4all.nl/~weegen/eelis/iso-c++/testcase.xhtml

Answer (score 8):

`printf` can call `malloc`. Because of this, if you have some dangling pointers, calling `printf` can change the values pointed to by these. If your program was strictly conforming you wouldn't observe this kind of differences when calling `printf` though (as you rightly expect). At worst an allocation in `printf` could fail, but not silently corrupt other variables.

Comment: To test this, move your `printf` calls down below the last of your assignment statements.  That way, if `printf` is changing anything it will happen after the "important part" of the function takes place.

Answer (score 5):

I would suspect some problem with memory access / allocation and test with [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: I ran it through valgrind and it informed me that there were some uninitalized variables in the function. I tracked down the culprits (a pair of doubles I was using to keep cumulative sums) and initialized them properly and now it works.

So now I know why my code was giving the wrong answers - but I'm still mystified as to how calling printf could make it give the correct answers!

Comment: The only way I can think of to figure that out would be to look at the assembly code generated. Did you compile with optimisations ? Perhaps the printf makes some variables allocated on the stack instead of a register, and the result is different (probably by luck since the variables were unitialized)

Comment: David's last comment seems right to me - since the `printf` call will clobber registers, adding it will change the allocation of variables to registers/memory in the calling function.